# Disable Mouseover on cells of Daypilot Scheduler

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, daypilot

I am using [DayPilot](https://www.daypilot.org) Scheduler, when I `mouseover` on cells then resources are also hovering .

Question: How do I disable that?

Comment: when you say `hovering` - what exactly do you mean?  i'm guessing `tool-tip` or similar but cant be sure...

Comment: if it is the tool-tip there a `ShowToolTip` property you can set to `false`.

Comment: @JohnB, no its not any tool-tip..just move the mouse over on cells the resources filed hovered

Comment: have you tried asking here?:https://forums.daypilot.org/question/new